# How to choose a predictive model between MSE and graphical plot (observed against predicted value)?

Tags: multiple-regression, lasso, ridge-regression, mse

After regularisation with Lasso and Ridge, I currently have a model under each, taking MSE values as shown below,

*MSE, Ridge =  0.1923102*

*MSE, Lasso =  0.1292252*

Both models have the same number of regressors, thus in terms of parsimony, they are on equal standing.

However plotting their observed against predicted values (as shown below), I observed that the regularisation under Ridge seems to explain the bottom tail better, whereby with Lasso,the bottom tail seems to vary more. However, in terms of overall fit, Lasso seems to fit better in general, whereas Ridge seems to underestimate the observed value.

In this case, would it be better to prioritise MSE and choose the Lasso model over Ridge model as a predictive model. Or should I compromise MSE, and choose Ridge in order to withold a better explaining power in the lower tail?

[image: Ridge] [image: Lasso]

Comment: Are you assessing MSE and creating your plots based on in-sample data, or based on a holdout sample?

Comment: @StephanKolassa  the plots above and mse are calculated on a holdout sample. However, still waiting to receive a larger handout sample to test the model chosen, this is currently what I have to work with. Generally, looking for advice on which I should be adopting and pointers I should be looking out for when adopting

Comment: Just a small quibble: it is more common to have observed values on the x axis and predicted values on the y axis; you have the opposite.